# To check whether Office is installed in a server

Tags: ms-office

How do I programmatically find whether MS OFfice is installed in a list of server in a Windows Network.

Comment: which office app you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

[For XP Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/orkXP/HA011364611033.aspx)

You have to search in registry:
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\*version*\Common\InstallRoot

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was 'why would you have Office installed in servers?' but maybe you're using the word server to mean something more general.

The link provided by Svetlozar, above, seems to be for determining if Office is installed locally,  not on a list of servers in a Windows network.

Wouldn't it be considered a security risk to allow remote access to this kind of information?